# Objective C - one-many relationships data retrival from core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

[image]

I have a core data model (has made a simplifie to make it easier to explain what I want to do).

An author can published many books and a book can have many chapters.
In the example I want to retreive all the Autors that has a chapter in a book where readDate is null.

```
- (NSArray *)incompleteChaptersInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSFetchRequest* fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Author class])];
    NSPredicate* uidCondition = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"books.chapters.readDate!=nil"];
    [fetch setPredicate:uidCondition];

    NSArray* resultArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

..
..
```

This does not work and I am struggling finding out how this can be done.
At the moment I am 
declare an author mutablearray.
- get all authors
    - loop through all their books
          - loop through all the chapters
          - if readDate is null add it to the author array

This works but I want to solve this without the nested loops.

Comment: Wat was your output when you run above code? Also, change books.chapters.readDate!=nil to books.chapters.readDate==nil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this looks like a case for: `SUBQUERY`

```
NSFetchRequest* fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Author class])];

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(books, $cd, SUBQUERY($cd.chapters, $m, $m.readDate == NULL).@count != 0).@count != 0"];
[fetch setPredicate:uidCondition];
```

not sure if it was == nil or NULL what to check for in dataBase. I'm only checking for values so can't tell this at the moment

Comment: This should work as well (+1). It might be interesting to compare the generated SQLite queries to see if there is a difference.

Answer (score 7):

For nested to-many relationships a SUBQUERY is necessary (as @geo already correctly said).
But one SUBQUERY should be sufficient:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(books, $b, ANY $b.chapters.readData == NULL).@count > 0"]
```

(I assume that "books" and "chapters" are really to-many relationships, even if your 
diagram show them as to-one relationship.)

Comment: if chapters are also a NSSet, is it still possible to access them with the . operator? I'm sure I have tried this some time ago and a second SUBQUERY was necessary :/ but if it works it's fine :)

Comment: @geo: As far as I know, `ANY a.b.c == d` works if *exactly one* of the relationships on the lhs is "to-many" and the others are "to-one". I have not checked this particular query but it worked in similar cases.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to do with the data afterwards, don't forget that you can also fetch the chapters where readDate is nil, and then go back to books and authors.

Comment: this is possible, but you have to extract one by one and have no completed array as result ;) possible, but not so practicle :)

Comment: Of course. That what I mean by "depending on what you need to do with the result" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also checkout the Sensible TableView framework, which will handle all Core Data fetches and automatically display the data in your table views. Saves me tons of time.